# Can a stepper motor produce enough torque to open a door?

Tags: stepper-motor, torque, electro-mechanical

From a few sources, I read that a stepper motor produces more torque at slow speeds. I want to create an automatic door opener (for a living room). Can a stepper motor produce enough torque for this purpose?

Stepper motors of different sizes are available, so I guess using a bigger one will be better, since it can produce more torque. Is that correct?

Comment: Will thevstepper motor operate the lock / catch and the the door is spring loaded or operates under gravity with rising butt hinges?  Or will you need two motors? Or one motor one solenoid?

Comment: @SolarMike stepper motor will be used to rotate the door.spring loaded idea is also good .I just want to know various possibilities .

Comment: You have not asked for various possibilities though - you focused on a stepper motor.

Comment: @SolarMike     You are right . So do you think stepper motor can produce enough torque for door opening ?

Comment: Probably not but I don’t have data sheets on all stepper motors - easily found if you look for them. I would consider something like a wiper motor from a car.

Comment: @SolarMike do you have time (few minutes) for chatting ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106626/discussion-between-shawn-and-solar-mike).

Comment: No thank you, I have given you a couple of suggestions.

Comment: Anything can provide enough torque given that it may take 60 minutes to open the door. You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Andyaka you can tell range of time we can obtain ?

Comment: You need to research a stepper motor and find out what its torque-speed graph is then take it from there with an appropriately geared down mechanism.

Comment: @Andyaka  Then in that case i should mention size of door , exact location of door on earth , exact time when i want to rotate etc .

Comment: You need to do some more research into what I said.

Comment: \$\color{red}{\text{Why do you say this:}}\$ *do you also want to no that what is angle of building, and weather i can go out buy motor during quarantine ?* \$\color{red}{\text{and why do you say this:}}\$ *do you want to know if it is legal to do such experiments at home , financial budgets ?*? \$\color{red}{\text{Are you trying to be rude (because it sounds like it).}}\$

Comment: @Andyaka you started it first ,by saying 60 minutes  can't you help by telling that stepper motors can provide torque from this range to this and how much time will it take in best case. Don't try to fear me by using red  fonts

Answer (score 1):

Yes possible, But you will need a pulse generator, to control the door!

Comment: can you few more details like how much time will it take open i.e will door will open slow or fast ?

Comment: Yes. it will open slow or fast.  a question with this level of imprecision will not get precise answers.